# Load the birthdays into the calendar

Tags: 2013, list, calendar

I'm new to SharePoint.
I created a list with personal details, where the names, addresses, birthday dates, etc. of all employees are stored.

1. How can I load the birthday dates of the employees into a new
   calendar app?
2. Can I use the same calendar app for displaying different calendars (e.g. birthdays, meetings, etc.)? Like in Google Calendar, where I can have several calendars (in the left menu) and I can choose which of them I want to display.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to move them into a new calendar app? You can create a calendar on any list you have, and you should be able to overlay it on other calendars.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a date column for birthdays you can create a calendar view directly on that list.

If you want to create multiple calendars you can stack them together (overlay them like in Outlook).  This will only work for Calendar Apps though - not list calendar views.

1. To do that open your calendar.
2. In the ribbon select the  "Calendar" tab and find the Calendar Overlay button.
3. Add in the URL of your other calendar and select a color and there you go.

The simplest method is to create a view in your list showing just the name and birthday, then copy that data directly into your birthday list.  You may also want to consider just creating the Calendar App and adding columns for your other data, and just moving all the data there if that is the primary purpose of the list, that remove one layer of duplication.

The next step up is creating a workflow on your list that copies that data.  You can build it with SharePoint Designer and they are not too difficult to do, even if you have not used them before.  This would require you update each list item or manually start the workflows on each item though to get it to work.

And the most valuable - automating it all, is the toughest if you do it your self because it requires varying levels of development effort, depending on which route you take.

If you are configured to support "apps" I would consider looking in the Office Store to see if there are any there that might also meet your needs. I have not been thru there in a while but I would be shocked if there were not 3 or 4 different birthday / anniversary apps out there.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand, how to import the birthday dates from the employee list into the calendar. Yes, there are stored there in a date column.

Comment: If you want to keep them in separate lists you need to build a workflow on the employee list that copies the fields you want over to your birthday calendar.  If you have never built a workflow before you can review the "how to" here from Microsoft:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you actually want the end result to be. Your contact list is a list of names, details, and the birthday however it wont be able to display the birthdays in a repeating pattern. What the Calendar App offers you is the ability to add an item to the calendar and enable a repeating patterns you need.

You might be best off creating the calendar app and then manually adding their birthdays and call it a day. (how many people in total do you need to add?)

Summary: 
we will use the **quick edit** mode in standard list views to Copy / Paste the data from your contact list into the calendar, then you can apply the Recurrence pattern so the birthdays repeat in the calendar app. (note the calendar by default has a calendar styled view as its default but you can create new view or modify the existing **All Events** View that displays the data as a list)

Steps:

1. Go to your contact list and select or modify a view so it displays the Names and birthdays next to each other. (list ribbon > list settings > modify a view)
2. return to the view and change it to quick edit so you can copy the data. (List ribbon > **Quick Edit** mode under the *view format* section)
3. Select / Copy your data. (similar to excel)
4. Go to your calendar app and select the **All Events** view (Calendar ribbon > current view drop down menu > All Events)
5. Modify the All Events view so the Item Title and Start Date are next to each other with Title on the left and start date on the right (just as they were in your other list) (list ribbon > modify view)
6. save the view and then toggle the format to **quick edit** mode as you did in the other list.
7. **paste** the data into the calendar from your other list. (be sure the columns your pasting into are in the same order / format)
8. Switch back to the normal **view** and edit the entries one by one to create the repeating or Recurrence patterns so they repeat every year.